# Homepage for multi-language website

Tags: php, seo, multilingual

I'm currently working on a multi language website project. I have two languages in my website (Russian, English). English is the main language.

Basically the problem is: Should I make the homepage like `www.example.com/en` OR `www.example.com/`? And maybe redirect to sub directory from main page?
Or my main home page should have a sub directory or should it be empty?

Comment: I would set my homepage to the default language that you have chosen then redirect the user to another local url if your server detects they are from an english speaking country

Comment: @Dave, Default with a sub directory? of (en)? or just clean domain name, I mean I can make the whole website english without directory and make the russian with sub directory basically, do i have to specify the language in sub directory for my main language?

Comment: Yeah sorry @Dea that's the way I was thinking

Comment: @Dave, so I will make my default language without a sub directory hope it will be fine in terms of Google who causes problem all the time

Comment: if you look over to http://www.booking.com/ and watch the url change  just after the domain you will notice it adapts to the language, which you can change and have it reflect in the url. Please notice US English is it's default

Comment: @Dave, I actually wanted to make my website like booking.com URL structure and not directories, but there aren't many articles on the web on the multi language anyway and google says go for directories,i wanted to url Like follows(hotels.ru.html, hotels.en.html)

Comment: Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on StackOverflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on the network site Pro Webmasters at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

better way is set default language as on defult url .. if you use framework like laravel of som... Language strings are stored in files within the app/lang directory. Within this directory there should be a subdirectory for each language supported by the application.

```
app
/lang
    /en
        homepage.php
    /es
        homepage.php
```

read this article i hope u can get basic idea about process of thishttps://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a language slug for every language, even the default one. Then, you can detect and redirect users based on their browser's language, redirecting always by 302. In your case, it would be as follows:

- www.domain.com, redirect by 302 to browser's language or other selected by default, for example English: 302 to www.domain.com/en.
- www.domain.com/en
- www.domain.com/ru

It is important to remember that you should redirect users only if they are requesting the canonical domain or the default subdomain: www.domain.com or domain.com